# Daemon thread keep alive in ipython when running python script

Tags: python, multithreading, ipython

Consider the following lines of code:

```
import time
import threading

keepAlive = True

def threadHandler():
    print('thread started')
    while keepAlive:
        time.sleep(1)
    print('thread ended')

tt = threading.Thread(name='SomeThread',target=threadHandler)
tt.setDaemon(True)
tt.start()
```

If I copy and paste these lines into ipython, then, whenever I want, I can just type `keepAlive = False` to make the thread exit. Which is good!

However, if I save the code above into a file named `foo.py` and then run it in ipython by doing `%run foo.py`, doing `keepAlive = False` in the ipython shell has absolutely no effect and the thread just carries on executing. It's as if `threadHandler()` had its own private copy of what the value of `keepAlive` was when the thread started. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can run the script in the notebook's namespace using the `-i` option. See [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).

```
%run -i "foo.py"
```

2) Or get the code and then `exec`.

```
# Get the code as a string
fin = open("foo.py", "r")
code = fin.read()

# Execute the code
exec(code)

# Doing this in a cell in notebook terminates the thread
keepAlive = False
```

Comment: This does work, yes. But why does it work this way and not the other way? Are there other ways of making it work?

Comment: @unkown, this is just trying to simulate your first code where you write the code in a notebook cell. Will edit if come up with alternate solution.

Comment: @unkown, I have modified my ans with a more natural way of doing it.